GND on top and bottom layer?
I am designing a 2-layer PCB where the bottom layer is dedicated to GND. Should I connect the unused areas of the top layer to GND as well? What are the benefits or drawbacks of doing this? Or maybe should I remove this polygon from top layer?
Im running 24 MHz clock sygnal through this board. This is board for MEMS digital microphone.


Have you considered using it for Vcc?

Have you considered if this might become a patch antenna for a floating Common Mode SMPS supply noise?

Connecting unused areas to GND can help reduce electromagnetic interference (EMI).

It's fine to ground the top pour, and add ground stitching vias in strategic places: at ground pins, on either side of long traces, inside corners created by loops or crossings of traces, and periodically across the board (say every several cm) and around the perimeter.
